# replace single quote and double quote in files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I took a dump from postgres which created a bunch of CSVs, which have single (') and double (") characters in a few huge files.

How can I replace these with \" and \' in linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed "s/['\"]/\\\\&/g" <<< "abc'def',\"foo\",bar"

abc\'def\',\"foo\",bar
```

If you want to avoid escaping already escaped quotes then use:

```
sed -E "s/(^|[^\\])(['\"])/\\1\\\\\\2/g" file
```